# cart price rules collection filter with store id not working in magento1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, shopping-cart-price-rules

cart price rules collection filter with store id not working in magento1.

```
$rules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
       ->getCollection()
       ->addStoreFilter($storeId);

OR 

$rules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
       ->getCollection()
       ->setStoreId($storeId);
```

Both not working. 
anyone have idea about store filter?

Answer (score 2):

Salesrule collection class has no store filter method. check following class:

```
app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Rule/Collection.php
app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Resource/Rule/Collection/Abstract.php
```

So if you want to get rule store wise then try following way:

```
$rules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
    ->getCollection();
$rules->getSelect()->join(
    'salesrule_label',
    'main_table.rule_id=salesrule_label.rule_id',
    array('label')
)->where('store_id=?', $storeId);
```

Comment: I know this is quiet old subject but: It does not work for me for some reason, how can I get a collection of rules for a single store ?
I tried: $rules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); with no luck ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *addWebsiteFilter()* method located in *app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Resource/Rule/Collection/Abstract.php*

```
// Get current website_id
$website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();

$rules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addWebsiteFilter($website_id);
```